# Extract rolling sequences of the same vector

Tags: r, function, vector, sequence

If I have the vector

`V <- c(1:8)`

and I need the sequence of `V[8:5]`, then `V[7:4]`, and so on until `V[4:1]` in a single operation to use into a function, how it is supposed to be written?

Something like this:

`V[((k+1):1):(n-(k-(k:0)))]` where k=3 (the lags) and n=8 (the length of the vector)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and add a language tag. [tag:R]?

Comment: It looked to me like the proposed item needed the word "where" added, but please [edit] your question if I misunderstood.

Comment: What is the expected output? Another vector or a list of vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a first approach using `sapply`:

```
sapply(rev(V[1:5]), function(i) paste0(seq(x[i+3], x[i]), collapse = " "))
[1] "8 7 6 5" "7 6 5 4" "6 5 4 3" "5 4 3 2" "4 3 2 1"
```

Depending on the desired **format** of your output this may need to be adapted. A possible alternative is this:

```
lapply(rev(V[1:5]), function(i) seq(x[i+3], x[i]))
[[1]]
[1] 8 7 6 5

[[2]]
[1] 7 6 5 4

[[3]]
[1] 6 5 4 3

[[4]]
[1] 5 4 3 2

[[5]]
[1] 4 3 2 1
```